# External application UI menu access in Ubuntu

Tags: menu, button

[Slides - Guided images(Google+ uploaded)](https://plus.google.com/112901921506377871688/posts/LEXnYgYpiaX)

How do I trigger external application menus from my own application on Ubuntu(Linux) , Windows(xp, 7,8 ,10) , OS X, Android...

The above link show 3 self explanatory photos and uses Blender to illustrate the concept I am after...

**End goal** : a custom switch panel to trigger menu items direct with my own shapes, buttons whatever...(no mouse , no menu shuffle...)

Here my example provides Blender Application menus. I am talking(writing) system wide(any applications) controls ...clickable or otherwise!

Years back on WindowsXP - an external app could send "mouse click" events to another applications menus/windows/buttons. Using some skill I would imagine that all of the applications menu items could be mapped to external buttons that way.
One would expect to find similar ability on more recent Windows versions (7,8..10?)although I have little to no experience there...

Automator on Mac , WinAutomation on Windows could at worst case scenario be employed to move the mouse cursor in a scripted/pre-recorded way? Can this be made reliable , fiddling free though??

Ubuntu has the power of Linux on its side ...perhaps there??

Please provide me with clues. Hope this guide explains precisely what my aim is!

Thank you